# How to have multiple viewPager.setCurrentItem(positions) placed for different OnClick methods?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

Lets say Activity A has 5 buttons. Each button will take you to Activity B which is a tabbed activity with 5 tabs. When I click button1 I want it to take you to tab1, button2 = tab2, button3 = tab3, etc. I'm using setCurrentItem but it's only working for the first and last button. The rest in-between will take you to tab1.
What code do I need so button2 will take me to tab2. Do I need and if else statement? Help would be much appreciated.

ActivityA.java

```
  public void Button1(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), TabbedActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("Tab1", 0);  //2 or whatever you want
    startActivity(intent);
}

public void Button2(View view) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), TabbedActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("Tab2", 1);  //2 or whatever you want
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);


}

public void Button3(View view) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), TabbedActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("Tab3", 2);  //2 or whatever you want
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

}

public void Button4(View view) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), TabbedActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("Tab4", 3);  //2 or whatever you want
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

}

public void Button5(View view) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), TabbedActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("Tab5", 4);  //2 or whatever you want
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

}
```

ActivityB.java

```
final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

    final int position1 = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("Tab1");

    final int position3 = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("Tab3");
    final int position2 = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("Tab2");
    final int position4 = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("Tab4");

    final int position5 = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("Tab5");


    PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter
            (getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(position1);
    }
    {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(position3);
    }
    {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(position2);
    }

    {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(position4);
    }

    {

        viewPager.setCurrentItem(position5);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are putting values in different keys in your intent. Put the same key instead:
Activity1:

```
public void Button1(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), TabbedActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("position", 0);  //2 or whatever you want
    startActivity(intent);
}

public void Button2(View view) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), TabbedActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("position", 1);  //2 or whatever you want
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
}

public void Button3(View view) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), TabbedActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("position", 2);  //2 or whatever you want
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
}

public void Button4(View view) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), TabbedActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("position", 3);  //2 or whatever you want
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
}

public void Button5(View view) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), TabbedActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("position", 4);  //2 or whatever you want
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
}
```

Activity2:

```
    final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter
        (getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
viewPager.setCurrentItem(getIntent().getExtras().getInt("position",0));
```

Comment: brooo, Drilon Blakqori God speed to ya man. It worked brilliantly. I been stuck on this for awhile. I think this calls for a bong hit. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Please don't use **startActivityForResult** You can use only one key to pass tab index in intent like

```
    public void Button1(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), TabbedActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("tabIndex", 0);  
        startActivity(intent);
    }
 public void Button2(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), TabbedActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("tabIndex", 1);  
        startActivity(intent);
    }
 public void Button3(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), TabbedActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("tabIndex", 2);  
        startActivity(intent);
    }
 public void Button4(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), TabbedActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("tabIndex", 3);  
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

In activityb get

```
final int position = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("tabIndex");
PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter
            (getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
     viewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public void Button1(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), TabbedActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("tabPosition", 0);  //2 or whatever you want
    startActivity(intent);
}

public void Button2(View view) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), TabbedActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("tabPosition", 1);  //2 or whatever you want
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);


}

public void Button3(View view) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), TabbedActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("tabPosition", 2);  //2 or whatever you want
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

}

public void Button4(View view) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), TabbedActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("tabPosition", 3);  //2 or whatever you want
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

}

public void Button5(View view) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), TabbedActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("tabPosition", 4);  //2 or whatever you want
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

}
```

Then in your view pager class

```
final int currentPosition = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("tabPosition");
```

Set your views like this

```
PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter
            (getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(currentPosition);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using different key values in for each ButtonView use single key and get value in position variable and just get the value in single integer variable and set the currentIten using that variable.

e.g.
Activity A:

```
public void PcHealth (View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), TabbedActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("TabPosition", 0);  //2 or whatever you want
    startActivity(intent);
}

public void Wifi (View view) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), TabbedActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("TabPosition", 1);  //2 or whatever you want
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);


}

public void Misc (View view) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), TabbedActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("TabPosition", 2);  //2 or whatever you want
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

}

public void HowTo (View view) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), TabbedActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("TabPosition", 3);  //2 or whatever you want
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

}

public void Shortcut (View view) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), TabbedActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("TabPosition", 4);  //2 or whatever you want
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

}
```

ActivityB.java:

```
final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

    final int position = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("TabPosition");


    PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter
            (getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

  viewPager.setCurrentItem(poisition);
```